# How do I return the object from a collection with simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a simple_form input field that looks like this:

```
<%= f.input :parents, collection: (@node.family_tree.nodes - @node.parents - [@node]).uniq, label: "Parent 1" %>
```

But this produces HTML like this:

```
<option value="13">Jack</option>
```

Where the `value` is the `ID` of the object selected from the collection.

However, I would like for the entire object to be returned as an AR object or an array. For instance, I would love to be able to get something like this:

```
<%= f.input :parents, collection: (@node.family_tree.nodes - @node.parents - [@node]).uniq, value_method: :parents, label: "Parent 1" %>
```

Produces this:

```
<option value="[#<Node id: 36, family_tree_id: 2, created_at: &quot;2015-01-28 23:19:28&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2015-01-28 23:19:28&quot;, name: &quot;Mesty&quot;, ancestry: &quot;13/35&quot;, ancestry_depth: 0, max_tree_depth: 0>]">Resty</option>
```

But using `value_method: :self` doesn't work.

So, using these examples, how do I return the entire node object for `id=13` rather than just the `13`?

Comment: This approach seems problematic, you'd be effectively caching internal values of the object on the webpage for as long as the user had it open. Why do you need to do this? Usually you'd just get the object from the database by id when it is submitted.

Comment: Hrmm...that's a good point. I may need to rethink my approach to setting these values.

Comment: @fd. The issue I am running into is that I am passing the result of that form to a gem. I can't hardcode that the gem does a lookup on my class for the record, so that's the issue. The gem should just accept my object, and then work on the object. Or do you have another suggestion for how I might do a lookup in the Gem (which I am editing) with just the ID of the object passed without knowing the name of the class?

Comment: like fd said, you just need to get the object using the ID, when you submit your form, the ID will be present in your params hash. Then you can do something like `@node = Node.find params[:id]` to get the object.

Comment: @Finks Like I said before....what is happening is that the form is not passing this attribute to a controller local to my app. It is passing it to a gem (aka a gem controls the setter method for `parents` attribute referenced in the form input). So what is happening is this form is just passing the ID of a random object to an app-agnostic gem. How does the gem know that it should do `Node.find(params[:id])`? Why should it not do `TreeNode.find(params[:id])`? In other words, how can I let the gem lookup `Node.find(params[:id])` without hardcoding my class (aka `Node`) in the gem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should be using simple_form's `f.association` rather than `f.input` for dealing with relations.

See https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations

Comment: I can't use an `association` because `.parents` isn't an explicit association on my `Node` class. It is an inherited method from the mounted `ancestry` gem. But your idea is right...I do want an object passed in, like an association except that I can't use the association method of simple_form.